# Custom C# card view type control

Tags: c#, winforms, cardview

I'm a beginner, writing a quiz program in a C# Winforms program.
Fundamentally, I would like to be able to display the question and answer pairs in a series of "cards".
Each card must have the ability to display the text, and have some other functionality with a button or two.

The [devexpress card view control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3466/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/View-Technology/Card-View) looks a bit like what I'd like.
But the price is a prohibitive.

I'm not sure if the answer lies in making a custom control, that gets copied for each item of data at run time ?

I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction, as I seem to have got stuck on this for a while now and am not sure where to start.

Comment: There're a lot of solutions: 1) make your own control, while making it, you'll learn a lot about winforms controls; 2) make panel with some elements on it; 3) making picturebox and use it as you want by filling it with texts and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev express controls are there for rich people, us poor folk can implement our own!

You'd have to create a `CardsPanel` control, with a collection of `CardViewModel`.  It'd obviously read each item of the collection, create a `Card` control for it, set it's viewmodel and add it to the `Panel`.  You basically answered your own question!

As for nice smooth movement within that CardControl, it might require some code for Lerp and Slerp adding, but that shouldn't be too hard.  You can monitor additions to the collection with an `ObservableCollection` when needed.  The design seems very simple from your link and wouldn't be too hard to emulate with ordinary Winforms.

Here's a complete example:

```
public class CardsPanel : Panel
{
    const int CardWidth = 200;
    const int CardHeight = 150;

    public CardsViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public CardsPanel()
    {
    }
    public CardsPanel(CardsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        ViewModel.Cards.CollectionChanged += Cards_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Cards_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
    }

    public void DataBind()
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        Controls.Clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < ViewModel.Cards.Count; i++)
        {
            var newCtl = new CardControl(ViewModel.Cards[i]);
            newCtl.DataBind();
            SetCardControlLayout(newCtl, i);
            Controls.Add(newCtl);
        }
        ResumeLayout();
    }

    void SetCardControlLayout(CardControl ctl, int atIndex)
    {
        ctl.Width = CardWidth;
        ctl.Height = CardHeight;

        //calc visible column count
        int columnCount = Width / CardWidth;

        //calc the x index and y index.
        int xPos = (atIndex % columnCount) * CardWidth;
        int yPos = (atIndex / columnCount) * CardHeight;

        ctl.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
    }
}

public partial class CardControl : UserControl
{
    public CardViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public CardControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CardControl(CardViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DataBind()
    {
        SuspendLayout();

        tbAge.Text = ViewModel.Age.ToString();
        tbAge.Name = ViewModel.Name;
        pbPicture.Image = ViewModel.Picture;

        ResumeLayout();
    }
}

public class CardsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CardViewModel> Cards { get; set; }
}

public class CardViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Bitmap Picture { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cardsPanel1.ViewModel = LoadSomeData();
        cardsPanel1.DataBind();
    }

    private CardsViewModel LoadSomeData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<CardViewModel> cards = new ObservableCollection<CardViewModel>();
        cards.Add(new CardViewModel()
        {
            Age = 1,
            Name = "Dan",
            Picture = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\daniel.rayson\\Pictures\\CuteKitten1.jpg"))
        });
        cards.Add(new CardViewModel()
        {
            Age = 2,
            Name = "Gill",
            Picture = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\daniel.rayson\\Pictures\\CuteKitten1.jpg"))
        });
        cards.Add(new CardViewModel()
        {
            Age = 3,
            Name = "Glyn",
            Picture = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\daniel.rayson\\Pictures\\CuteKitten1.jpg"))
        });
        cards.Add(new CardViewModel()
        {
            Age = 4,
            Name = "Lorna",
            Picture = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\daniel.rayson\\Pictures\\CuteKitten1.jpg"))
        });
        cards.Add(new CardViewModel()
        {
            Age = 5,
            Name = "Holly",
            Picture = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\daniel.rayson\\Pictures\\CuteKitten1.jpg"))
        });            
        CardsViewModel VM = new CardsViewModel()
        {
            Cards = cards
        };
        return VM;
    }
}
```

You can see here that's I've stuck some testing data in there, but the overall concepts are there and it's a base you can jump off.

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe the FlowLayoutPanel is a better option for the CardsPanel base class ?